# Outlook and VB.net - wrong access rights when adding an attachment to mailItem

Tags: vba, outlook

In MS Outlook 2003 VB script I want to copy attachment from one mailItem to another. The source mailtItem is a template message.
The code I am using is this:

```
Sub copyAllAttachments(source, target)
  Dim fileName, i
  For i = 1 To source.Attachments.Count
    fileName = fileSystem.GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\" & source.Attachments.Item(i).FileName

    On Error Resume Next
    source.Attachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile(fileName)
    On Error Goto 0

    target.Attachments.Add fileName, 1
    fileSystem.DeleteFile fileName, True    
  Next
End Sub
```

This works fine with 50 users, but one.. He always has an error on the line `target.Attachments.Add fileName, 1` saying, that the file cannot be created. and that he should check the access rights on the folder where he wants to create the attachment in.
His settings does not seem to be different from others, the folder is his TEMP folder

Can anyone, please, help me to solve this mystery or give me a hint, where to look? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Can you log the problematic attachment file name?
Are you sure the error comes from the Attachments.Add line, and not SaveAsFile line?
It sure sounds like you have an attachment with an invalid file name - Outlook does not perform validation, so it is possible that Attachment.Filename property contains a value that is not a valid file name on Windows. Or it could have no value at all - you really need to check the validity of the file name and also probably the Attachment.Type property: SaveAsFile method (or even the Filename property) will fail for the, for example, embedded OLE attachments.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. The problem was partially solved for that one problematic user by system admins. They deleted and created his whole temporary folder again, so Outlook now does not have any more problems. But I am pretty sure, that it was failing on the line `target.Attachments.Add fileName, 1`. Also, I know that the name if the file was not a problem. The form was putting there a template with one file attached to it. And this operation was OK with 50 or so users, but failed with one.
For me this remains a mystery of Microsoft Office suite. There are still some really strange bugs.